# How can I prevent the page from going back to login page after logging?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

After logging in, if the user clicks on the go back button from the browser, they'll be redirected back to login page.

I've tried setting router.push:

```
 if (session) {
    router.push('/homepage');
  } 
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          fullWidth
          sx={{ textTransform: 'none' }}
          variant="outlined"
          startIcon={googleIcon}
          onClick={() => signIn('google', { callbackUrl: '/homepage' })}
        >
          Entrar usando a conta do Google
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
```

But it doesn't work properly. It goes back to login page for a sec and then redirects the user to /homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You could `replace` the location when the user logs in, this would result in the `/login` page not being in the history when the user tries going back.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the variable `session` receives a value that understands as a `true` value. For this reason, the condition is met and a redirect to the home page occurs

Comment: The redirect to the homepage occurs because I've set the callbackUrl to do so. So the signIn funcion actually logs the user in and redirects them to /homepage